# How to compare two sets to each other?

Tags: python, comparison

I'm currently attempting to solve "Question 349 - Intersection of two arrays" on leetcode and was trying to return an array of their intersection. My goal was to make two separate sets that took in the values of each array because I need unique values.

I'm confused as to how I'm supposed to iterate through both sets now to return the elements that match and return that. This is my code and I'm having the issue where it tells me that `bool object is not iterable` which makes sense:

```
class Solution:
    def intersection(self, nums1: List[int], nums2: List[int]) -> List[int]:
        set1 = set()
        set2 = set()
        newList = []
        for i in nums1:
            set1.add(i)
        for j in nums2:
            set2.add(j)
        for i in set1 and j in set2:
            if (set1(i) == set2(j)):
                newList.append[i]
        return newList
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a sets [`intersection`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset.intersection) method.

```
def intersection(self, nums1: list[int], nums2: list[int]) -> list[int]:
    set1 = set(nums1)
    set2 = set(nums2)
    result = set1.intersection(set2)
    return list(result)
```

And this can be shortened to

```
def intersection(self, nums1: list[int], nums2: list[int]) -> list[int]:
    return list(set(nums1).intersection(nums2))
```

---

There's no need to iterate over the list manually to create a set. [`set`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-set) accepts an iterable as a parameter so using a list is fine.

Comment: when you created result, is it a new set that takes in the intersection values? Thanks! Was just confused what result was.

Comment: Yes. The `intersection` method gives back a set. I edited the answer and added a link to the documentation. And since you want to give back a list from your function we have `return list(result)` in the next line.

Comment: If any of the answers were successful, could you consider to upvote/accept them?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `&` (set intersection) operator.

```
>> s1 = {1, 2, 3}
>> s2 = {2, 3, 4}
>> s1 & s2
{2, 3}
```

Alternatively use the non-operator method [`intersection`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset.intersection) which contrary to the operator also excepts an iterable (not necessarily a set) as its argument.

```
>> s1.intersection(s2)
{2, 3}
>> s1.intersection([2, 3, 4])
{2, 3}
```

Convert to a list if necessary.

In your case:

```
class Solution:
    def intersection(self, nums1: List[int], nums2: List[int]) -> List[int]:
        return list(set(nums1) & set(nums2))
```